# get bus name as set by "dbus_request_name" of a message sender

Tags: c, dbus

For debugging purposes I want to know the sender name of a dbus message. But `dbus_message_get_sender` returns the senders unique name which usually is something like this: `:1.60`. I'm looking for a way to get the name as set by `dbus_request_name`.

org.freedesktop.DBus interface provides a method to query *unique name* that corresponds to the *set name* which is called`GetNameOwner`. But I can't find a method to do the opposite?

---

One method I figured is to get a list of all registered names with the `ListNames` method, then query the unique name for each *name* with `GetNameOwner` until a match happens. This should work but I still think that there should be a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One method I figured is to get a list of all registered names with the ListNames method, then query the unique name for each name with GetNameOwner until a match happens. This should work but I still think that there should be a simpler way of doing this.

That is the correct way to achieve what you want.

There is no method on the [`org.freedesktop.DBus` interface](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-messages) to map from a unique name (for example, `:1.5`) to a well-known name (for example, `org.bluez`), because each unique name may be the owner of zero or more well-known names.

Arguably there could be an `org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNamesForOwner()` method which would map from a unique name to an *array* of well-known names, but nobody has written that yet.